# how to use iloc to get the matrix of the sublevel

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I got a square matrix with two levels:

```
index = [('A','a'),('A','b'),('B','a'),('B','b')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=index)

        A                B
        a        b       a       b
A   a   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    b   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
B   a   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    b   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

expected results with iloc:

```
       a        b
  a   NaN     NaN
  b   NaN     NaN
```

I would like simply got the sub-square matrix A (a,b)(a,b) with iloc.
I tried a dozen way and search on stackoverflow but I cannot find a way to get my matrix with iloc. With loc it is simple, but I need to iterate and I don't want to navigate into the index to get the label for performance issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `df.iloc[:2,:2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) first for remove top levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
index = [('A','a'),('A','b'),('B','a'),('B','b')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),index=index, columns=index)
print (df)
            A                   B          
            a         b         a         b
A a  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776
  b  0.004719  0.121569  0.670749  0.825853
B a  0.136707  0.575093  0.891322  0.209202
  b  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697  0.978624

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
print (df)
          a         b         a         b
a  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776
b  0.004719  0.121569  0.670749  0.825853
a  0.136707  0.575093  0.891322  0.209202
b  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697  0.978624

a = df.iloc[:2,:2]
print (a)
          a         b
a  0.543405  0.278369
b  0.004719  0.121569
```

Because if use `iloc` only get `MultiIndex` in index and columns:

```
b = df.iloc[:2,:2]
print (b)
            A          
            a         b
A a  0.543405  0.278369
  b  0.004719  0.121569
```

Comment: It is complicated because in reality the number of subindex B are different from subdindex A. To avoid problem with this approach I have to evaluate the longer of each subindex and so access to the string index.

Comment: So need first select by `A` and then use `iloc`? Something like `print (df.loc['A','A'].iloc[:2,:2])` ?

Comment: I decided to drop the level, work with the sub-matrix, reset and restore the index of the original, and modifiy the values with [:]. It is not here I gained a lot of time, but it simplified my code.

Answer (score 0):

Using jezrael's example, is this what you are after?

```
df = df.iloc[[0,1],[0,1]]
Out[825]: 
            A          
            a         b
A a  0.543405  0.278369
  b  0.004719  0.121569
```

If you only want the second level,

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
print(df)
Out[835]: 
          a         b
a  0.543405  0.278369
b  0.004719  0.121569
```